# Generic type of a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

I have the following code :

```
public abstract class ListPresenter<TView, TModel, TEntity> : Presenter<TView, TModel>
    where TView : IListView<TModel>
    where TModel : EntityListViewModel<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public ListPresenter(TView view, TModel model)
        : base(view, model)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the third parameter? If I try to use :

```
public abstract class ListPresenter<TView, TModel> : Presenter<TView, TModel>
    where TView : IListView<TModel>
    where TModel : EntityListViewModel<IEntity>
```

I get:

Error   3   The type 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.SaleListViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'PuntoVenta.Presentation.ListPresenter'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.SaleListViewModel' to 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.EntityListViewModel'. C:\Users\Marc\Dropbox\Source\PointOfSale\PuntoVenta\Presentation\ListSalePresenter.cs   26  20  PuntoVenta.UI

even EntityListViewModel< IEntity > will always be true.

```
public abstract class EntityListViewModel<TEntity> : ViewModelBase, IEntityListViewModel<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity 
{
    private BindingSource Entities { get; set; }

    private string searchQuery = string.Empty;

    public EntityListViewModel()
    {
        SearchQuery = string.Empty;
        Entities = new BindingSource();
    }

    public TEntity Selected
    {
        get { return Entities.Current as TEntity; }
        set { Entities.Position = Entities.IndexOf(value); }
    }

    public string SearchQuery
    {
        get { return searchQuery; }
        set
        {
            searchQuery = value;
            NotifyProperty("SearchQuery");
        }
    }

    public List<TEntity> DataSource
    {
        set
        {
            Entities.DataSource = value;
            NotifyProperty("DataSource");
        }
    }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
}

public interface IListView<TModel> : IView<TModel>
    where TModel : ViewModelBase
{
    event EventHandler OnSearchQueryChanged;
    event EventHandler OnSelectRequested;
}

public abstract class ViewModelBase : IModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class SaleListViewModel : EntityListViewModel<SaleView>
{
    private bool _ShowPendingOnly = false;

    public SaleListViewModel()
    {
    }

    public bool ShowPendingOnly
    {
        get { return _ShowPendingOnly; }
        set
        {
            _ShowPendingOnly = value;
            NotifyProperty("ShowPendingOnly");
        }
    }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid to use generic type on declaration of `EntityListViewModel`.

There is no need of declare with generics in this case whether the objects always implement `IEntity` interface.

```
public abstract class EntityListViewModel
                      : ViewModelBase, IEntityListViewModel<IEntity>
```

You also need to change any reference in this class to `TEntity`.

```
public IEntity Selected
{
    get { return Entities.Current as IEntity; }
    set { Entities.Position = Entities.IndexOf(value); }
}

public List<IEntity> DataSource
{
    set
    {
        Entities.DataSource = value;
        NotifyProperty("DataSource");
    }
}
```

At this point, you can declare `ListPresenter` as

```
public abstract class ListPresenter<TView, TModel>
                      : Presenter<TView, TModel>
                                 where TView : IListView<TModel>
                                 where TModel : EntityListViewModel<IEntity>
```

Comment: EntityListViewModel has this property that use generics : public TEntity Selected
        {
            get { return Entities.Current as TEntity; }
            set { Entities.Position = Entities.IndexOf(value); }
        }

Comment: It can work but in this case I have to cast the type everytime I use the Model.Selected property

Comment: Then... you want to avoid `get { return Entities.Current as IEntity; }` conversion, isn't it?

Comment: Well.. I also lose : `public List<TEntity> DataSource
        {
            set
            {
                Entities.DataSource = value;
                NotifyProperty("DataSource");
            }
        }`

Comment: You are not showing this part of code on your original question... ;) What `class` contains this fragment of code?

Comment: No problem. I think that it is the same situation of `Selected` property... If you can ensure that `List<TEntity>` will be always an object of `List<IEntity>` type, then you only need to switch `TEntity` generic by `IEntity` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just restrict `IListView` and `EntityListViewModel` to `IEntity`?

```
public abstract class ListPresenter<TView, TModel> : Presenter<TView, TModel>
    where TView : IListView<IEntity>
    where TModel : EntityListViewModel<IEntity>
```

You might need to make `IListView` and `EntityListViewModel` covariant:

```
public interface IListView<out T>
```

Comment: That was my first try but I get : Error 3 The type 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.SaleListViewModel' cannot be used as type parameter 'TModel' in the generic type or method 'PuntoVenta.Presentation.ListPresenter<TView,TModel>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.SaleListViewModel' to 'PuntoVenta.ViewModels.EntityListViewModel<PuntoVenta.Entities.IEntity>'.